# Is there a way to save a Django object and update other objects without a recursion loop?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   fk = models.ForeignKey(Foreign, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   display = display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   ...
```

I'd like to override the save method to turn off display for other events that share the fk value. However, I keep reaching infinite recursion loops because if I override the save method and then save the other objects, it keeps calling the function. Is there a way to only run the save method on the first object that's saved and not keep creating recursive instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work [**`.update(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) a `QuerySet` of other objects, with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Event(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(Foreign, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # …

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.fk_id is not None and self.display:
            Event.objects.filter(
                ~Q(pk=self.pk), fk_id=self.fk_id
            ).update(display=False)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But this also immediately shows that there are ways to circumvent the [**`.save(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) on a model, therefore just overriding `.save(…)` will *not* be sufficient, since there are ORM methods that circumvent the `.save(…)` and pre-save and post-save signals (which are triggered by the the `.save(…)` method).

You can also add a constraint to enforce that there is at most one `Event` for each `fk` that has `display=True`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Event(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(Foreign, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # …

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('fk',),
                condition=Q(display=True),
                name='only_one_display_per_fk'
            )
        ]
```